# open source syntax highlighter tool?

Tags: open-source, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for an open source, cross platform (Windows & Linux at least) command line tool to take some code (C++, but multiple languages would be sweet), and spit out valid a XHTML representation of that code, with syntax highlighting included.

Ideally the XHTML should just wrap the code with `<span>` and `<div>` tags with different classes so I can supply the CSS code and change the colouration, but that's an optional extra.

Does anyone know of such an application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can recommend [Pygments](http://pygments.org/). It's easy to work with and supports a lot of languages. It does what you want, i.e., it wraps the code in `<span>` tags:

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

code = 'print "Hello World"'
print highlight(code, PythonLexer(), HtmlFormatter())
```

gives

```
<div class="highlight">
<pre><span class="k">print</span> <span class="s">&quot;Hello World&quot;</span></pre>
</div>
```

and you can then use one of the supplied style sheets of make your own.

You can also call it via it's `pygmentize` script. The script can format the output in different ways: HTML, LaTeX, ANSI color terminal output.

Comment: I ended up using pygments - it's simply brilliant! Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/) can save any code it highlights to "colored" HTML (it runs on several platforms). There is [GNU hightlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) too. And tons of others.

Comment: can you give an example how to do it in vim ?

Comment: open your file in gvim
then <ESC> :syn on
:TOhtml

the vim screen split, one buffer for the html, one for your original file. Then you save the html rendered file and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

There is very good one, driven by XML, fast and opensource: http://sourceforge.net/projects/colorer/

Comment: Being driven by XML is only a feature in the Java world... :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall if [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) has a command-line program but even if it doesn't, it shouldn't be hard to whip one up. It does a great job of taking code and generating pretty, coloured HTML/XHTML, even with line numbers (or every X line numbers, even) and other helpful features.

Answer (score 1):

[Enscript](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) looks like what you are asking for :

1. spit HTML (or PS, or RTF) from ascii files
2. It includes features for `pretty-printing' (language-sensitive code highlighting) in several programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how helpful this will be, but my team uses doxygen to produce documentation, which happens to provide color syntax highlighting on our code views as well as a side bonus. Never really needed it, but it does it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using ruby, you want [coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/).

Answer (score 0):

I'll add [my own one to the list](http://www.shrinkrays.net/tools/csharp-syntax-highlighter.aspx), it colors C# but could be adapted for C, C++ and Java. 
It produces the inline styles by default and a pre tag.

The source is there in C#, you'll need to grab mono/monodevelop and compile it as as a console app, so it's not shrink wrapped in that respect.